# Where do I get multiwindow function?

Tags: multi-window

I bought a galaxy 3 tablet with 4.2.2 system. The multiwindow option isn't there at all.  I tried resetting the device but that did not help.

Answer (score 3):

Pull down notification window, and enable it.

[image]